# Relative url in Visual web part

Tags: sharepoint-2010, web-parts

In my Visual web part I'm using relative url like following and it's working fine . But I assume it will not work when I deploy my project in different site structure on another server. So my question is how to make links,urls dynamic which will work in all the scenarios.

```
../../something.aspx
```

Please note I have some JQuery files included in `<script>` tag I can't only rely on building dynamic url using code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rishi,

Are you using a document library to store the page?  If so, you could use SPDocumentLibrary.DefaultViewURL.  If you're trying to navigate to a different web, then you can get a web's URL from SPWeb.Url.

Best,
-Tony

Comment: Thanks @Tony; Actually I'm including JQuery files into ascx by adding <script> tag there I can't use classes so trying to use traditional way.